# JUnit: is it possible to create a Test Suite that executes all test of classes that share a naming convention?

Tags: java, testing, junit, frameworks

I am aware that I can make a TestSuite enumerating all the classes that I want, for example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({SQLServerTests1.class, SQLServerTest2.class, ... })
public class AllSQLServerTests {}
```

However I have almost 100+ classes and I don't want to have to remember to include any new one in the @SuiteClasses annotation.

As my classes have a naming convention (starting with "SQLServer" for example) I am searching for a way to do something like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(prefix="SQLServer")
public class AllSQLServerTests {}
```

is it possible with plain JUnit? with spring or any other framework?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by custom `Runner`. But your need to find all the test classes in classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tag'em

You can add many tags to each test or test class:

```
@Test
@Tag("red")
@Tag("production")
public void testWithColour() {...} 



@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@IncludeTags("red & !production")
public class JUnit5Example {
   //...
}
```

You can also use `@ExcludeTags` but it cannot co-exist with `@IncludeTags`

## Run all in test package

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("com.acme.megaproduct.slowtests")
public class JUnit5Example {
   //...
}
```

## Write custom Test Runner

Perhaps none of the above can acommodate your needs, in which case you can add custom filtering by writing your own runner.

See [here for step by step how to do it](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-custom-runners). 
Then you just use it like:

```
@RunWith(MyCustomRunner.class)
public class CustomTestSuite {
   //...
}
```